# BrowserMob Proxy warning and exception java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, remotewebdriver, browsermob

I am using the BrowserMob Proxy Interface version 2.1.0-beta-3 (latest) with RemoteWebDriver and am seeing the following Warning/Exceptions regularly when I run it. It seems like the remote end stopped/crashed/closed connection while the driver was trying to navigate to a URL. However I don't really get what could have caused it to close.

```
LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-1é WARN org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection - (AWAITING_INITIAL) °id: 0x6d0bba70, /162.222.73.15:18708 => /<ip>:13000é: Caught an exception on ClientToProxyConnection
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:384)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:447)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
°LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-0é WARN org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection - (NEGOTIATING_CONNECT) °id: 0xead90d4d, /162.222.73.15:19770 => /<ip>:13000é: Caught an exception on ClientToProxyConnection
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:384)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:447)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
°LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2é WARN org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection - (NEGOTIATING_CONNECT) °id: 0x79fa97f4, /162.222.73.15:9147 => /<ip>:13000é: Caught an exception on ClientToProxyConnection
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:384)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:447)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
°LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-3é WARN org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection - (AWAITING_INITIAL) °id: 0xaa25c51b, /162.222.73.15:19720 => /<ip>:13000é: Caught an exception on ClientToProxyConnection
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:384)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:447)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Most of the time the execution continues and it actually navigates to the desired URL and captures the HAR but sometimes it just hangs after which I have to kill the process.

Also, keep getting these errors if I keep the process running for some more time. This seems like an SSL certificate issue but it usually piggybacks off the first one.

```
°LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-3é ERROR org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection - (AWAITING_INITIAL) °id: 0x71209d6c, /162.222.73.15:6210 => /<ip>:13000é: Caught an exception on ClientToProxyConnection
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:358)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:230)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1607)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1776)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1068)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:890)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:764)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1135)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1025)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:965)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    ... 11 more
```

Have been observing these exceptions too, although I do not think they are related to broswermob or could be

```
[LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-0] ERROR org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection - (NEGOTIATING_CONNECT) [id: 0x2ea1eced, /162.222.73.13:7919 => /<ip>:13000]: Caught an exception on ClientToProxyConnection
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 802e0100020015000000100100800700c00300800600400200800400800000ff322036ba42651dc8aa28877107bb772c
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:977)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:230)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] ERROR org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection - (NEGOTIATING_CONNECT) [id: 0xcee6232c, /162.222.73.13:31136 :> 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:13000]: Caught an exception on ClientToProxyConnection
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol SSLv3 not enabled or not supported
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:358)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:230)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol SSLv3 not enabled or not supported
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1348)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:519)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:796)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:764)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1135)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1025)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:965)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol SSLv3 not enabled or not supported
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:281)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:269)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:431)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:167)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:853)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:851)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1285)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1161)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1064)
    ... 13 more
```

I have tried looking and searching online but don't seem to have a good solution. Any suggestion or direction would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "sometimes it just hangs after which I have to kill the process"? Do you end up killing the browser/HTTP client, or the BrowserMob Proxy instance?

Comment: I have to kill the Http client that is making the request.

Answer (score 0):

You have raised several different exceptions that you are seeing in your logs.  In the case of the ***Connection reset by peer***, that is one that I am also seeing a lot of as well.  I have not been able to confirm this yet, but I do have a theory on what is causing this.

I am running test suites that load many pages.  And when the first page tests are complete it loads the next page.  However there may still be network requests in progress when it does that.  What then happens to the connections that are still open at the moment when the web browser requests a new page?  I suspect that the browser closes those connections before it moves on.  This would cause BrowserMob Proxy to get an unexpected close connection event.  When it does it probably throws the ***Connection reset by peer*** exception which then gets logged.

If this is the case, then this is probably a non-issue.  It should be possible to create some test scenarios to prove this out.